# Google spreadsheet: birthday reminder via conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

Please, help to do conditional formatting to highlight birthdays (which are written as MM/DD/YYYY) in Google Spreadsheet.
Should be 3 conditions:

1. to highlight a birthday we used formula

=and(month(B1:B1000)=month(today()),day(B1:B1000)=day(today()))

which works

2. to highlight a day before birthday we used formula

=and(month(B1:B1000)=month(today()),day(B1:B1000)=day(today()-1))

but this formula don't work in cases when birthday day is 1st of month

3. need to highlight date in case between seven days before birthday and 1 day before birthday

Answer (score 1):

Here are some rules (assuming the custom CF formulas are being applied to the range B1:B1000:

**Birthday is today**

`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"m/d"))=TODAY()`

**Birthday is tomorrow**

`=TEXT(B1-1,"m/d")=TEXT(TODAY(),"m/d")`

**Birthday is between 2 and 7 days from today**

`=(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"m/d"))>(TODAY()+1))*((DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"m/d"))-7)<=TODAY())`

The first two (for today or tomorrow) are simpler than what you were using.

The third will flag, as I've said, if the birthday is in the next 2 - 7 days. Your post says that you want between 1 and 7 days in this rule; but that would overlap with your "tomorrow" rule.

Rules must account not only birthday ranges that fall between months, but those that fall between years (i.e., flagging a Jan 1 birthday when it is December 31 of the previous year), which is why the final rule perhaps seems a bit long.